# How can I get handle of Windows process in Go?

Tags: windows, go, winapi

I'm trying to call function `RegisterDeviceNotificationW` of `user32.dll`. But the first param of the function is the "handle to the window or service that will receive device events" (this I getted from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationa#parameters)).

Based on [Cloud Printer Connector](https://github.com/google/cloud-print-connector/blob/master/winspool/win32.go#L1233) I tried to get the handler with `svc.StatusHandler()`, but does not work for me, every time I run I get the follow error:

> The handle is invalid.

Well, using the same code of the [examples](https://github.com/golang/sys/tree/master/windows/svc/example) of `sys` I created my own "service", replacing the `beep` function by `RegisterDeviceNotification` (the same code of [google](https://github.com/google/cloud-print-connector/blob/master/winspool/win32.go#L1233)) and sent the name of my service and the value returned from `svc.StatusHandler()`, but I received again the same message: "The handle is invalid."

#### Function RegisterDeviceNotification

```
var (
    u32                            = syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll")
    registerDeviceNotificationProc = u32.MustFindProc("RegisterDeviceNotificationW")
)
```

Here is where I need sent a valid Handler

```
func RegisterDeviceNotification(handle windows.Handle) error {

    var notificationFilter DevBroadcastDevinterface
    notificationFilter.dwSize = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(notificationFilter))
    notificationFilter.dwDeviceType = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE
    notificationFilter.dwReserved = 0
    // BUG(pastarmovj): This class is ignored for now. Figure out what the right GUID is.
    notificationFilter.classGuid = PRINTERS_DEVICE_CLASS
    notificationFilter.szName = 0

    r1, _, err := registerDeviceNotificationProc.Call(uintptr(handle), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&notificationFilter)), DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE|DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES)
    if r1 == 0 {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

#### Call the function

```
func (m *myservice) Execute(args []string, r <-chan svc.ChangeRequest, changes chan<- svc.Status) (ssec bool, errno uint32) {
    h := windows.Handle(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(m)))
    err := RegisterDeviceNotification(h)

    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

NOTE: I tried too with the pointer of "myService":

```
h := windows.Handle(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(m)))
err := RegisterDeviceNotification(h)
```

**EDIT:** I tried with [GetCurrentProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocess), but does not work:

> Retrieves a pseudo handle for the current process.

```
h, err := syscall.GetCurrentProcess()
err = RegisterDeviceNotification(windows.Handle(h))
```

The question: **How can I get a valid handle of the process in Go?**

PS: If exists any problem with my question, please, let me know to improve.

Comment: Did you make any pogress?

Comment: Looking at the RegisterDeviceNotification docs you need a Handle to either a Service or a Window. Maybe there's the problem.

Comment: no, I have not had any progress

Comment: Pity. I'm on a similar problem and will let you know if I find something

Comment: The service type has a member `h` which is the handle you need.  https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/22da62e12c0cd9c1da93581e1113ca4d82a5be14/windows/svc/service.go#L142

Comment: According to the RegisterDeviceNotification API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationa), you should provide a handle to the Window or a Service. That's why you have an error when you provide the process's handle. Do you create a Window with your app?

Comment: I don't remember, I'm not on that project anymore 

Answer (score 0):

syscall.GetCurrentProcess () can be used like this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    kernel32, err := syscall.LoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer kernel32.Release()

    proc, err := kernel32.FindProc("IsWow64Process")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    handle, err := syscall.GetCurrentProcess()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var result bool

    _, _, msg := proc.Call(uintptr(handle), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&result)))

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", msg)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "syscall"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    ProcessUtils{}.SetWinNice(13716, windows.HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS)
}

var (
    kernel32        = syscall.MustLoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    procOpenProcess = kernel32.MustFindProc("OpenProcess")
)

const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

type ProcessUtils struct {
}


func (ProcessUtils) GetProcessHandle(pid int) windows.Handle {
    handle, _, _ := procOpenProcess.Call(ToUintptr(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS), ToUintptr(true), ToUintptr(pid))
    return windows.Handle(handle)
}

func (u ProcessUtils) SetWinNice(pid int, priority uint32) error {
    handle := u.GetProcessHandle(pid)
    return windows.SetPriorityClass(handle, priority)
}
func ToUintptr(val interface{}) uintptr {
    switch t := val.(type) {
    case string:
        p, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(val.(string))
        return uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(p))
    case int:
        return uintptr(val.(int))
    default:
        _ = t
        return uintptr(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some more details explaining your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I wrote a while ago to handle this, it was working last time I checked. I've created wrapper functions for a bunch of winapi calls.

```golang
package main

import "syscall"

// import the required winapi DLLs and functions
var (
    dllKernel32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
    procOpenProcess = dllKernel32.NewProc("OpenProcess")
    procCloseHandle = dllKernel32.NewProc("CloseHandle")
)

// when passing this to the OpenProcess function it will get
// a handle with the PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS permissions
const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | uintptr(0xFFFF)

func main() {
    pid := uint32(123456)
    inheritHandle := uint32(1)

    handle, err := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, inheritHandle, pid)
   
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    ... // whatever your code wants to do

    err = CloseHandle(handle)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}

// Wraps the winapi OpenProcess function
func OpenProcess(desiredAccess uintptr, inheritHandle uint32, pid uint32) (uintptr, error) {
    // call the winapi function to get a handle
    handle, _, err := procOpenProcess.Call(desiredAccess, uintptr(inheritHandle), uintptr(pid))

    // check for errors
    if handle == 0 || err != nil {
        return r1, err
    }

    // return the handle
    return handle, nil
}

// Wraps the winapi CloseHandle function
func CloseHandle(handle uintptr) error {
    // call the winapi function to close the handle
    r, _, err := procCloseHandle.Call(handle)

    // check for errors
    if r == 0 || err != nil {
        return r1, err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Make sure to close the handle when you're done using it, don't want to keep random handles open indefinitely.

Here's some resources to help you with what's going on here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get the handle of a process given the PID:

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights
const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = windows.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | windows.SYNCHRONIZE | 0xffff

func GetWindowsHandle(pid int) windows.Handle {
    handle, err := windows.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, uint32(pid))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return handle
}
```

I believe you also need to make sure to call `windows.CloseHandle(handle)` when you are done with it.

Full example:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights
const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = windows.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | windows.SYNCHRONIZE | 0xffff

func SetPriorityWindows(pid int, priority uint32) error {
    handle, err := windows.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, uint32(pid))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer windows.CloseHandle(handle) // Technically this can fail, but we ignore it

    err = windows.SetPriorityClass(handle, priority)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "hello.py")
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Set priority to above normal
    err = SetPriorityWindows(cmd.Process.Pid, windows.ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
}
```