# How to call windows.SetPriorityClass (windows)

Tags: windows, go

I would like to exec a program from golang and set the priority of the child process to "above normal".

Here's a sample program that doesn't work because I can't figure out how to access the child process's "handle" (which is unexported), which is needed to make windows syscalls:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")

    // launch hello.py python program
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "hello.py")
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Set priority to above normal
    handle := cmd.Process.handle // <-- compiler error; unexported field
    windows.SetPriorityClass(handle, windows.ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)

    // wait for the program to finish
    err = cmd.Wait()
}
```

Am I just supposed to do dirty hacks like using `unsafe` to gain access to the unexported field?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing `cmd.Process.handle` with `unsafe` + `reflection` does work, but seemed very hacky. This is the cleanest/safest way I've found to do this:

```
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights
const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = windows.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | windows.SYNCHRONIZE | 0xffff


func SetPriorityWindows(pid int, priority uint32) error {
    handle, err := windows.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, uint32(pid))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer windows.CloseHandle(handle) // Technically this can fail, but we ignore it if it does

    err = windows.SetPriorityClass(handle, priority)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

Full example:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights
const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = windows.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | windows.SYNCHRONIZE | 0xffff

func SetPriorityWindows(pid int, priority uint32) error {
    handle, err := windows.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, uint32(pid))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer windows.CloseHandle(handle) // Technically this can fail, but we ignore it

    err = windows.SetPriorityClass(handle, priority)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "hello.py")
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Set priority to above normal
    err = SetPriorityWindows(cmd.Process.Pid, windows.ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
}
```

References:

- [How can I get handle of Windows process in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316616/how-can-i-get-handle-of-windows-process-in-go)